# CMake FindPython3 failing to find interpreter on Windows

Tags: python, windows, cmake, visual-studio-2017

Here's the start of a `CMakeLists.txt` file that I'm using:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
project(hello-pyext)

find_package(Python3 COMPONENTS Interpreter Development)
message(STATUS
    "Python: version=${Python3_VERSION} interpreter=${Python3_EXECUTABLE}")
if(NOT Python3_FOUND AND Python3_Development_FOUND)
    #   find_package() will not abort the build if anything's missing.
    string(JOIN "\n" errmsg
        "  Python3 and/or development libs not found."
        "  - Python3_FOUND=${Python3_FOUND}"
        "  - Python3_Development_FOUND=${Python3_Development_FOUND}"
        )
    message(FATAL_ERROR ${errmsg})
endif()
```

When built with `cmake-3.12.4-Linux-x86_64` (downloaded from `cmake.org`) on Linux, it works fine, finding both the Python3 interpreter and development headers/libraries installed via `apt-get`. (Python2 is also installed on the system, but I've confirmed that the interpreter it finds is the Python 3 one.)

On Windows 10, however, it finds the development headers/libs but not the interpreter, printing:

```
-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.17763.0 to target Windows 10.0.14393.
-- Could NOT find Python3 (missing: Python3_EXECUTABLE Interpreter) (found version "3.6.6")
-- Python: version=3.6.6 interpreter=Python3_EXECUTABLE-NOTFOUND
CMake Error at hello-pyext/CMakeLists.txt:14 (message):
    Python3 and/or development libs not found.
    - Python3_FOUND=FALSE
    - Python3_Development_FOUND=TRUE
```

I get the same results in both MinGW Bash and Developer Command Prompt for VS 2017, with all of the following versions of CMake:

- `cmake version 3.12.18081601-MSVC_2` that came with Visual Studio 2017.
- `cmake-3.13.4-win64-x64` downloaded from `cmake.org`.
- `cmake-3.14.0-rc3-win64-x64` downloaded from `cmake.org`.
- `cmake-3.14.20190305-gc9ce4f-win64-x64` (latest development version as of this edit) downloaded from `cmake.org`

As best I recall, I've only ever used the standard installers from `python.org` to install Python. "Programs and Features" lists Python 3.4.4 (64-bit), Python 3.6.6 (64-bit) and Python Launcher as being installed. The `py` launcher correctly launches both of these, as well as `python` itself being in my path:

```
C:\>py --version
Python 3.6.6
C:\>py -3.4 --version
Python 3.4.4
C:\>python --version
Python 3.6.6
C:\>python3 --version
'python3' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
C:\>
```

I've also checked this against a fellow developer's machine who installed Python 3.5 via Anaconda as his primary Python, as well as a 3.6 install from `python.org`, and gotten the same results.

The deprecated `FindPythonInterp` does seem to work:

```cmake
find_package(PythonInterp)
message("
    PYTHONINTERP_FOUND=${PYTHONINTERP_FOUND}
    PYTHON_EXECUTABLE=${PYTHON_EXECUTABLE}
    PYTHON_VERSION_STRING=${PYTHON_VERSION_STRING}
")
```

```
-- Found PythonInterp: C:/Program Files/Python36/python.exe (found version "3.6.6")

    PYTHONINTERP_FOUND=TRUE
    PYTHON_EXECUTABLE=C:/Program Files/Python36/python.exe
    PYTHON_VERSION_STRING=3.6.6
```

I'm not too familiar with Windows, so I'm not sure where to go from here to debug this. Does anybody have any idea why `FindPython3` is unable to find the interpreter, or how I should start debugging this (beyond just reading the source code for `FindPython3`)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem here, as per [CMake issue 19024(https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/19024), is that I was doing a 32-bit build (the default, since I'd not configured with `-A x64`) on a system with only 64-bit Python installed. FindPython3 felt it had found the 32-bit development tools (though it hadn't), realized that it couldn't find a 32-bit interpreter and so set `Python3_FOUND=False`.

Doing a 64-bit build by configuring with `-A x64` fixed that problem.

The "finding 32-bit dev tools that aren't there" problem (causing it to print `Python3_Development_FOUND=TRUE` in the question above) was a bug in the `FindPython3` module which has been fixed by [MR 3103](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/merge_requests/3103), available in the 20190316 nightly build. Unfortunately this did not make it into the 3.14.0 release.

For reference, what you want to do to build your extension after FindPython3 as worked successfully is:

```
Python3_add_library(myext MODULE myextsrc)
target_link_libraries(myext other_target_on_which_it_depends)
```